# Date operation in the Query Builder withPostGIS layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, query, datetime

I would like to filter a PostGIS layer by a datetime (QDateTime) field. I only want to show elements newer then 14 days. I tried the following expression in the Quary Builder:

```
(day(now() - "creation_date")) <= 14
```

The same expression is working in the Field Calculator but not in the Query Builder.

Any idea what I did wrong? Using QGIS v3.22.3

Comment: Which query builder? In DB manager? There, you have to use PostGIS syntax, not QGIS expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`day()` is a QGIS Expression function, not a SQL function.
The proper SQL syntaxe is

```sql
(now() - "creation_date") <= '14 days'
```

or

```sql
EXTRACT( DAYS FROM now() - "creation_date") <= 14
```